# docpad don't generate in heroku

Tags: heroku, docpad

Locally everything works.
On heroku an [error](https://gist.github.com/npofopr/6915538#file-heroku-error)

My [config](https://github.com/npofopr/_altyncev/blob/master/docpad.coffee)
And [defaultpost.html](https://github.com/npofopr/_altyncev/blob/master/src/layouts/defaultpost.html.eco)

Started after a two-month renovation website downtime.

I'm add new post, update docpad -> push heroku -> this error.

What could be wrong?

Comment: The `Rendering the extension
"eco" to "html" on "defaultpost.html.eco" didn't do anything` error means that for whatever reason, your heroku app no longer has the docpad-plugin-eco module installed.  Did you change your package.json file and remove it accidentally?  Do you have the log file of the beginning of your git push that shows all the npm output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a push from another computer.

It worked.

Magic.